# MOQ - Why is below not mocking?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Anyone have any idea why below still calls YesService?

It almost seems like IYesService is considered separate to YesService..

Any ideas?

```
public interface IYesService
{
    string Hello();
}
public class YesService : IYesService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Yes";
    }

}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _mock = new Mock<IYesService>();
        _mock.Setup(x => x.Hello()).Returns("No");

        var service = new YesService();
        var result = service.Hello();

        Console.Write(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't use the `_mock`, you instantiate the `YesService` and call the method on that.

You can use mocking when you *consume* this interface:

```
public class ServiceUser
{
    private IYesService _yesService;

    public ServiceUser(IYesService yesService)
    {
        _yesService = yesService;
    }

    public string CallService()
    {
        return _yesService.Hello();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var serviceMock = new Mock<IYesService>();
serviceMock.Setup(x => x.Hello()).Returns("No");

var service = new ServiceUser(serviceMock.Object);
var result = service.CallService();
```

Comment: I thought the whole point of MOQ was to mock YesService.Hello to return predefined value? How would you rewrite this?

Comment: With mocking you mock a specific instance, not _all_ instances of that interface or class. See my last edit for actually using a mock.

Comment: @DrZeuso You are not mocking `YesService.Hello()`, you are mocking `IYesServicve.Hello()`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an instance of YesService (the concrete class) in your Main method. The var service line an be done away with, and the var result line should become:

```
var result = _mock.Object.Hello();
```

Try that...